# 'TestWindowPackage' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am not able to open the test Explorer

on machine had Visual Studios 2008, 2010, 2012.  Then installed 2015, then 2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 update 5

'TestWindowPackage' package did not load correctly , activity log error:

```
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [TestWindowPackage]</description>
<guid>{BFC24BF4-B994-4757-BCDC-1D5D2768BF29}</guid>
<hr>80131509</hr>
<errorinfo>Loading MEF components failed with the following exception:
```

The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) The specified argument cannot be empty.
Parameter name: commandContainers

Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowPackage.PackageContainer (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer")' on part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowPackage'.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowPackage.PackageContainer (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowPackage

Additional diagnostics here: 
MEF Import details for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowPackage

```
ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer
RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer
Satisfied by :
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.PackageContainer")
```

I have tried:
-Restarted Visual Studio

-Restarted PC

-Delete all files in AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

-Run VS with devenv /setup

-Run VS With devenv /setup /ResetSkipPkgs

-Repaired the VS installation

-Uninstall VS2013, Delete all visual studio files in app data, re install VS 2013 update 5

Answer (score 0):

Opened ticket with Microsoft via company support account, Case number 116081014529972

They told me to reformat my machine and not install Visual Studios out of order.

Comment: smart Microsoft :)

Comment: This started happening for me after I installed IIS. Prior to IIS install I did not have this problem, and installing IIS was the only thing I did from when it was working to when it became broken.
Reformatting the hard drive and reinstalling everything is a 2-3 day fix. Thanks MS!